# PANDAS Find the exact word and before word (multiple) in a column of string and append that, new column in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

**Dataframe looks like this**

```
col_a
Python PY is a general purpose PY language

Programming PY language in Python PY 

Its easier to understand  PY

The syntax of the language is clean PY
```

This code I have tried to achive this functionality but not able to get the expected output. if any help appreciated.

Here is the below code I approach with regular expressions:

```
df['col_a'].str.extract(r"([a-zA-Z'-]+\s+PY)\b")
```

**Desired output:**

```
col_a                                       col_b_PY     
Python PY is a general purpose language         Python PY purpose PY
Programming PY language in Python PY            Python PY Programming PY     
Its easier to understand  PY                    understand PY 
The syntax of the language is clean PY          clean  PY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple pattern would extract desired strings: `\w+\s+PY`

Explanation: `\w+` matches one or more word characters, then `\s+` matches one or more white spaces followed by `PY`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fwYTSS/2)

Comment: it's not capturing the second pattern 
`df['col_a'].str.extract(r"(\w+\s+PY)\b")
`

Comment: @Balu Weird, on demo it's showing that it captures as needed. Just see the demo.

Comment: @Balu, the problem is not the regex, but your code regarding capturing the second pattern.

Comment: just use.. df['col_a'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall('\w+\s+PY',x)))  @Balu

Comment: The regex is correct, but you need to concatenate all the matches together

Comment: Many thanks @Michał Turczyn  you came up another approach

Comment: @Balu You can optionally upvote answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using @Michal's regex:

```
import re
def app(row):
    return ' '.join(re.findall(r'\w+\s+PY', row.col_a))

df['col_b_PY'] = df.apply(app, axis=1)
```

You need to concatenate all the matches for each row in the applied function. It's possible to do this using `extractall` too, but I find this simpler and more straightforward.